# Save and restore ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> on activity resume

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I have an array list of hash map and in this array list of hashmap i am adding items when activity created by downloading data from a webservice. and i am passing it to adapter of listview and want to save it and restore among multiple visits to the activity so that it doesnt download data each time when activity is resumed. I have an idea of onsavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState , but i do not know how can we save and store arraylist of hashmaps.

Any one can help. Many thanks in advance......

Comment: both method's  `onsavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` not called when your Activity resumed these methods called only when any config Changes occur you will just need to declare it Static or Save as String in Shared Preference or you can also use Database to Store data Retrieved from Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one Constant.java file and Declare hashmap arraylist in this file, Please see below code for more information, it will solve your problem.

```
public class Constants {
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mResults = new 
                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
}
```

Comment: this will only work if you put your application to background. (e.g movetasktoback(); )